# Spring Generic Service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, generics, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a web application with Spring MVC, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate, the data access part is taken care of by the repositories provided by Data JPA

However, I'm planning to have a generic service layer (atleast for the common operations), is it a good practise? Or is it advised to not generalise it?

Comment: Broad question, broad answer... that depends.

Comment: Ok, depends on the app I'm developing?

Comment: On your app, on the kind of data you plan to use, on the kind of services you want to provide etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is simple (mostly CRUD) operations then you can access your `Repository` classes directly.

If you have additional server-side business logic that needs to be applied to data or if you need to orchestrate multiple data access calls together then adding a Service layer would be appropriate.

Comment: If one of the answer given is correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If part of you application will consist of repeating same actions on different objects, it can make sense to have a generic abstract parent class for common operations.

**You** will have to decide if the gain in de-duplication of code is worth the complexity of the generic. There is no general rule ...